# Use the "Snap During Transform" tool but with a hover or offset

Tags: modeling, transforms, snapping

I have a humanoid character mesh and am trying to model clothes around it. I'd like to use the `Snap during transform` option, but this makes the vertices I transform lie directly on the character's faces. Can I enable snapping but with an offset so that it snaps as if hovering over the character mesh?

Comment: AFAIK the offset option in snapping mode doesn't exist. Though you may snap your cloth mesh to the character mesh, then scale cloth with Alt+S to create a space between them.

Comment: @PaulGonet thanks for the tip! That seems to be a fitting workaround!